# Install freezes on splash image on Inspiron 5565

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, dell, amd-graphics

I want to dual boot Win10 and Ubuntu 16.04. I'm using a Dell Inspiron 5565 AMD (not Intel) laptop with touchscreen Radeon graphics 4GB. Preinstalled OS is Windows 10 home.

I've created unallocated space and fixed fast boot settings. I tried thumb drives and DVD with a fresh Ubuntu iso each time.

The installation process is freezing on the splash screen.

Does this message give any useful clues?

```
CPU: 0 PID:33 Comm: kworker/0:1 Tainted G D L 4.10.0-28 ...
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Some messages are expected and of those some will be errors, some will be warning, some will be something else like "FYIs". Most can be ignored.

Comment: The problem is I cannot install ubuntu alongside windows. Th process hangs up at the startup splash screen.

Comment: You should have said so right away ;-) but you can do it now by [edit]ing your question. While at that please provide details about the specific hardware (make/model, etc.), especially graphics. Most likely you need a workaround like adding `nomodeset`...

Comment: I edited to include info. Can you say more about the graphics point?

Comment: The Dell Inspiron 5000 uses a few different AMD APUs. Those are single chips with integrated graphics. A few recommendations: 1. Prefer newer releases like the current 17.04 (support for AMD graphics, particularly APUs, has improved a lot). 2. Make sure you're booting/installing in UEFI mode. More info at https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi .

Comment: I'm confident you won't need additional steps if you use the current Ubuntu release but if it still hangs then, in the first menu "Try Ubuntu", etc. highlight that option, press 'e' to edit and then add `nomodeset` in the same line where "quiet splash" is, as described at https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Ok. Thank you Michael. I googled nomodset and am happily on my way to a fresh install of my fav os. I was just about to take the box back to BB. For others with this issue, find the Youtube tute on how to set nomodset.